# Ionic 2: How to make menu that open from the bottom and play music inside it

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Ionic 2: How to make menu (in ionic 2) that open from the bottom that plays music inside it. Like I have attached some [image]screen shots

When you click on music then the new menu is opened from the bottom and display song details and music is also play inside it.[image]

I did not find any UI component in ionic 2 for my requirement Please help me if you have any idea?

I used 2 concepts but it won't work for me:
1)ActionSheet of ionic 2 documentation
2)content drawer(https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/)

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action sheets from ionic,
https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#action-sheets

Comment: thank you for your answer but action-sheet is not working for me @MDM